# Performance Issue with Windows server 2003 and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, php5, windows

I have a server runing on Windows Server 2003 and was installed Apache.

The server have around 900 HTTP connections at once. which is not that high.

The webpage is just a simple php page that return around 2KB of output.

I have the ff. Test case:

1. I let the site run normally, -> slow webpages
2. I put up an rand() to cut down half of the visitors. The CPU perfomance are always stays low, but the connections are high and webpages are slow.
3. I delete the record of that webpage on apache config. As I do a netstat, I still sees high http connection pointing to that address. The server return an 404 but it is still very slow. Connection stays high (900)
4. I change the DNS record and point to something else. Now it works normally.

**Additional details**

We just make another test where SendFile and MMAP is turned on. also Gzip is configured. Keep-alive: off.

the domain dns still point to my server. As we start the apache server, everything work perfectly fast. But after the connections reach around 600. It getting slow.

Conclusion:

Does that mean that Apache cannot handle that high number of requests? Is there any posible way to increase this number? Because base on my opinion, 900 req/s is not so high.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU utilization is staying relatively low, then you might check memory and maybe swap file utilization. You might also take a look at the various memory/buffer settings that may be adjustable across Apache as well.